# Doctrine - [Semantical Error] - Error: Class has no field or association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am trying to run a query with Doctrine's [DQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) within a Repository and I am getting the following error:

> QueryException in QueryException.php line 63:
>   [Semantical Error] line 0, col 100 near 'test_suite_id': Error: Class Application\Model\Entity\Page has no field or association named test_suite_id

### Associations

A `User` can have multiple `TestSuite`s. A `TestSuite` can have multiple `Page`s. As a result, I have a **One-To-Many** association between `User` and `TestSuite`, and `TestSuite` and `Page` respectively.

[image: Associations]

Here are my entities with only the relevant associations shown:

### User

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_email", columns={"email"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Model\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var TestSuite[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TestSuite", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $testSuites = [];
}
```

### TestSuite

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="test_suites")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Model\Repository\TestSuiteRepository")
 */
class TestSuite
{
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="testSuites")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn{name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var Page[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Page", mappedBy="testSuite", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $pages = [];

}
```

### Page

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="pages")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Model\Repository\PageRepository")
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @var TestSuite
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TestSuite", inversedBy="pages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="test_suite_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $testSuite;
}
```

### The Repository DQL Query

```php
public function findPageForUser(User $user, $pageId)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->add('select', 'p')
       ->from('Application\Model\Entity\Page', 'p')
       ->join('Application\Model\Entity\TestSuite', 'ts', 'WITH', 'p.test_suite_id = ts.id')
       ->join('Application\Model\Entity\User', 'u', 'WITH', 'ts.user_id = u.id')
       ->where('p.id = :pageId')
       ->andWhere('u = :user')
       ->setParameter('user', $user)
       ->setParameter('pageId', $pageId);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Please note, I'm only passing in the `User` and the `$pageId` here. It is up to the query itself to resolve whether or not the user, *via the test suite join*, has that specific page.

As you can see, the `Page` entity clearly has a `test_suite_id` foreign key column pointing to the `id` column of the `TestSuite` entity, and my schema reflects this.

### The Generated Query

> SELECT p FROM Application\Model\Entity\Page p INNER JOIN Application\Model\Entity\TestSuite ts WITH p.test_suite_id = ts.id INNER JOIN Application\Model\Entity\User u WITH ts.user_id = u.id WHERE p.id = :pageId AND u = :user

Other posts have suggested the following:

- Clear the cache - *I have no caching layer enabled*
- Restart Apache - *It made no difference*
- Rename "Colum" to "Column" - *I'm not that daft*
- Put the FQDN in `targetEntity` - *They're in the same directory so no need*

Why am I getting this issue, specifically, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Maybe by typo `{` instead `(`
in`@ORM\JoinColumn{name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DQL is statically typed, and the DQL syntax is about object properties, and not SQL columns.

Additionally, there is no need to select the associated entities directly: joins are automatically put in place by the DQL query component, and it correctly generates the required `ON` clauses in the outcome SQL.

Here is a version of your query that should work:

```
SELECT
    p
FROM
    Application\Model\Entity\Page p
INNER JOIN
    p.testSuite AS ts
INNER JOIN
    ts.user u
WHERE
    p.id = :pageId
    AND u = :user
```

Since `Application\Model\Entity\TestSuite#$user` is a `to-one` association, you can further simplify the query by removing one join condition:

```
SELECT
    p
FROM
    Application\Model\Entity\Page p
INNER JOIN
    p.testSuite AS ts
WHERE
    p.id = :pageId
    AND ts.user = :user
```

The associated DQL builder code for the latter of the above queries is as follows:

```php
public function findPageForUser(User $user, $pageId)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->add('select', 'p')
       ->from('Application\Model\Entity\Page', 'p')
       ->join('Application\Model\Entity\TestSuite', 'ts')
       ->where('p.id = :pageId')
       ->andWhere('ts.user = :user')
       ->setParameter('user', $user)
       ->setParameter('pageId', $pageId);

    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->setFetchMode("Application\Model\Entity\Page", "elements", "EAGER")
              ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: As per discussion in chat: `WITH` is to be used as an additional restriction clause on a join, or as a restriction on a so-called "arbitrary join" (a join between two not-associated entities). In all cases, DQL does not understand column names, only property names.